# html template with php tag stored in database getting issue with php tag values

Tags: php, yii

I do have html template with php tag stored in database. Now when I render the the view m getting the content from the database but the value for the php tag that which, I passed in view with an array is not getting like.

```
eg. 
in Controller
$databaseFiled = "select from database";
$this->render('view', array("model"=>find(), "field"=>$databaseFiled ))
in View.
<?php echo $databaseField ?> (dataBaseFiled = "<html>.....<?echo $model->id?>....</html>)
```

here I am not getting the value for *$model->id.*

So please help me find solution...

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you pass a model into a view the code looks something like:

```
$model = NEW ModelOfTable;
$model->find('id=:id', array(':id'=>$id);
$this->render('view', array('model'=>$model));
```

When you say `"model"=>find()` in your render call, yii doesn't really know what you are talking about.